# Link within Excolo Slider area does not work on my device

Tags: android, slider

I'm using the Excolo Slider on a web site and inside the image area I have inserted a text with link

this is the code:

```
<div class="container_12">
    <div id="preSliderA" class="grid_8">
        <div id="sliderA" class="slider">
        <%
            for (int n = 0; n < crmcc.getVLen(); n++) {
        %>
            <div style="background-image: url('<%=crmcc.getVFields(n, 0)%>'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;">
            <div class="testorotoimmob"><%=crmcc.getVFields(n, 1)%></div>
            <div class="bottonerotoimmob"><a href="<%=crmcc.getVFields(n, 2)%>"  class="testobottonerotoimmob">DETTAGLIO</a></div>
        </div>
        <%
            }
        %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I use the link "" ..." with pc I haven't problem, but with any browser on Android device the link not work.
I use the last version available of Excolo Slider in Tomcat web application.

Can I resolve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "the link not work"? What happens instead?

Comment: If I click with my finger on "a href" link inside the slideshow nothing happens.

Comment: Can you share the generated markup?

Comment: <div class="container_12">
 <div id="preSliderA" class="grid_8">
  <div id="sliderA" class="slider">
   <div style="background-image: url('immobili/3101_APPARTAMENTO_VENDITA_ASCOLI_PICENO_1.JPG'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;">
    <div class="testorotoimmob">3101 - APPARTAMENTO - VENDITA - ASCOLI PICENO PORTA MAGGIORE</div>
    <div class="bottonerotoimmob"><a href="/euro3immobiliare/3101_APPARTAMENTO_VENDITA_ASCOLI%20PICENO/"  class="testobottonerotoimmob">DETTAGLIO</a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all that markup

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understood your comment.